# vagrant up command SSL certificate problem

Tags: linux, vagrant

I'm on Windows 7. The Vagrant up command, it keep giving me this:

```
vagrant up Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider... ==> defau
lt: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install... 
default: Box Provider: virtualbox default: Box Version: >= 0 ==> default: Loadin
g metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64' default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubun
tu/trusty64 ==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) for provid
er: virtualbox default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trust
y64/versions/20190514.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box default: Download redirected 
to host: cloud-images.ubuntu.com default: An error occurred while downloading th
e remote file. The error message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this e
rror and try again.

SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I have searched the web for a solution but got nothing, also i'v try to reinstall the latest version of vagrant and virtual machine but got nothing

Any ideas?????

Comment: i used `vagrant box add --insecure ubuntu/trusty64`then `vagrant up` but now i am having **time out error**

Answer (score 0):

The problem i posted solved by pausing the antivirus on my pc.
after that i `vagrant up` again then i got the following:

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.
```

after so much trials oracle vm GUI gives me this message:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.
```

This usually solved from bios by enabling the VT-x graphics,but in my bios was no option like this so after going back to intel documentation it's turn out that my cpu doesn't support VT-x